# wpf TreeViewItem how to expand node asynchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I expand TreeViewItem with ~3000 items, application will be stuck for about 5 seconds. After searching for solution, I realised that write a custom virtualizing panel is the only way but is difficult for me.

Here is xaml I'm using (simplified):

```
    <controls:FileMapPresenter ItemsSource="{Binding RootSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}">
        <controls:FileMapPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="folder_template">
                <controls:FolderDataPersenter ItemsSource="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}"
                               ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}">
                    <controls:FolderDataPersenter.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </controls:FolderDataPersenter.Header>
                </controls:FolderDataPersenter>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="file_template">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:FileMapPresenter.Resources>
    </controls:FileMapPresenter>
```

*controls:FileMapPresenter* is derived from **ItemsControl**, and *controls:FolderDataPersenter* is derived from **TreeViewItem**.

FolderDataModel (simplified):

```
public class FolderData : ViewModelBase
{
    public FolderData(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private List<FileData> files = new List<FileData>();
    public List<FileData> Files
    {
        get { return this.files; }
    }

    private List<FolderData> subFolders = new List<FolderData>();
    public List<FolderData> SubFolders
    {
        get { return this.subFolders; }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    private AutoInvokeObservableCollection<object> source =
        new AutoInvokeObservableCollection<object>();
    /// <summary>
    /// ObservableCollection which contains all the files and subFolders
    /// </summary>
    public AutoInvokeObservableCollection<object> Source
    {
        get { return this.source; }
    }
}
```

FileDataModel (simplified):

```
public class FileData
{
    public FileData(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }
}
```

in controls:FolderDataPersenter, I try to cancel expanding call and put it into asynchronous, then add a expanding progress reporter to notify UI:

```
public class FolderDataPersenter : TreeViewItem
{
    public FolderDataPersenter()
    {
        VirtualizingStackPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(this, true);
        VirtualizingStackPanel.SetVirtualizationMode(this, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            (Action)this.setExpandingEventListener,
             System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    }

    private void setExpandingEventListener()
    {
        if (this.Template != null)
        {
            var expander = this.Template.FindName("Expander", this) as ToggleButton;
            if (expander != null)
            {
                expander.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += this.onExpanderPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            }
        }
    }

    private void onExpanderPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            this.IsExpanded = !this.IsExpanded; // no work here
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Business.TreeViewExpandingCounter.StepForward();
    }

    protected override void OnExpanded(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = this.DataContext as Models.FolderData;
        if (folder != null)
        {
            if (folder.SubFolders.Count > 100)
            {
                Business.TreeViewExpandingCounter.Finish += this.onExpandingCounterDone;
                Business.TreeViewExpandingCounter.Set(folder.SubFolders.Count);
            }
        }
        base.OnExpanded(e);
    }

    private void onExpandingCounterDone()
    {
        Business.TreeViewExpandingCounter.Finish -= this.onExpandingCounterDone;
    }
}
```

expanding progress reporter worked well but expanding asynchronously failed, application still stuck while expanding node.

so it seems I have returned to the first question "how to expand TreeViewItem faster?" which I have searched for half a day...

any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe try `ItemsSource="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay,IsAsync=True}"`... not sure if it helps but it might.

Comment: Actually I'm wondering why you're not using `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the folder presenter. But thats probably a side-issue.

Comment: @grek40 I don't know how to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to deal with two type objects in one list and multiple recursive layers...

Comment: Just saying, it's probably what you need, so you could decide to learn about it. Possible learning sources for [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/) and for a different approach on [lazy-loading Treeview](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/lazy-loading-treeview-items/) (without HierarchicalDataTemplate)

Comment: @grek40 Thanks. After I add `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and remove `ItemTemplateSelector`, everything works well, all the items expanded very fast now. So `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is not a side-issue actually...

Comment: Good to hear, maybe I find time to write a proper answer later (unless someone is faster than me, which would be completely fine^^)